# Short story from decades ago: The premise​ is a precursor to the movie "Avatar"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

An extremely deadly/hostile atmosphere on a planet/moon/asteroid is being exploited (mined?) by biological avatars controlled from orbiting ships. The protagonist begins to lose the distinction between his avatar "self" and "reality".

Comment: Hmm.  This is very terse.  And, do you actually know that it was a precursor to the premise of [Avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_%282009_film%29) or are you supposing that?  Can you remember anything else?  Most such requests for identification are no good unless they at least mention a timespan for when it was first read or viewed.

Comment: I was tempted to say "The Winds of Atlair" by Ben Bova, but reading the description of "Call Me Joe" it does seem to better match.

Comment: Christ Stratton - did  you mean "The Winds of Atlair"  in which Atlair would be some imaginary place, or "The Winds of Altair" which would be set on a planet orbiting the star Altair?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_in_fiction

Answer (score 11):

You question reminds me of the famous story "Call Me Joe" (*Astounding Science Fiction* April 1957) by Poul Anderson.

Humans in a space station orbiting Jupiter remotely control artificial lifeforms on the surface of Jupiter.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_Me_Joe[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_Me_Joe%5B1%5D)

[https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55693[2]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55693%5B2%5D)

Comment: Clifford Simak's story "Desertion" (Astounding Science Fiction, November 1944; later part of "City") is similar, except there is a physical transformation instead of remote teleoperation.

Comment: Bingo!!  The title has re-energized synapses long dormant. I am pretty sure i must have read "I am Joe" in a synopsis of Amazing at some point in the '60's while in high school. Thanks. (and Wickipedia has a comment that the concept is so close to "Avatar" that Poul Anderson should get credit for the story line.